# Python: numbers defined as 'Instances' instead of 'Int" after been read

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, instance

I'm working on a project and I'm stuck on a rare behavior of python.

I have a list which contains numbers (only integers).  The problem is that if I call the function `type()` for those numbers, they are marked as `instance` instead of `int`.  This makes me unable to perform any kind of mathematical actions over them, since trying something like this:

```
for elem in list:
   print elem+1
```

will show me the error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'instance' and 'int'
```

Is there a way to specify that those numbers are of `int` type?

Additional information: the list is read from a text file (The project is in fact a programming language, and the list is read through the parser).

Edit: here is a part of the code, this is where the list is been read at the Parser.

```
def p_exp_set_literal(symbol):
"""expression : OPENCURLY comma_list CLOSECURLY
              | OPENCURLY CLOSECURLY """
if len(symbol) == 4:
    start, _ = span(symbol, 1)
    _, end = span(symbol, 3)
    symbol[0] = Set((start, end), symbol[2])
else:
    start, _ = span(symbol, 1)
    _, end = span(symbol, 2)
    symbol[0] = Set((start, end), None)
```

`comma_list` is where the list is. After that is sent to the abstract syntax tree like this:

```
class Set(Expression):
"""Class to define a set"""
def __init__(self, lexspan, values):
    self.lexspan = lexspan
    if values is not None:
        self.values = values
    else:
        self.values = []
```

Here `values` is where the list is.

Comment: 1. Do not name variables as `list` 2. Can you give an example of your list?

Comment: Show us the code that creates the list.

Comment: `instance` is the type given to instances of old-style classes. Can you say what version of Python you're using?

Comment: @tony: that seems unlikely.  Among other reasons, `print elem+1` is *invalid syntax* in 3.4, and so those lines would raise a SyntaxError before they even executed.

Answer (score 1):

```
for elem in elem_list:
    try:
        print int(elem)+1
    except ValueError:
        print "Expected an int, was passed a {} - {}".format(type(elem), elem)
```